# Not able to install PHP 5.6 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-5.6

I have PHP 5.6 and PHP 7 installed on my laptop, but due to some libraries not working in PHP 5.6 (also not able to install them), I uninstall PHP 5.6 using `sudo apt-get purge php5.6-common`. Now I have a folder for PHP 5.6 inside of `etc` and PHP 5.6 contains `mods_available` folder (`mods_available` is empty). Now I am trying to install PHP 5.6` again and I tried following commands too many times but not able to do that.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Please check output [here](https://pasteboard.co/Hei89d2.png).

Next `sudo apt-get update`, and I think [this](https://pasteboard.co/Hei9urv.png) output is related to `ondrej` library

Then `sudo apt-get -y install php5.6` AND also `sudo apt-get install php5.6` output is [here](https://pasteboard.co/HeianFV.png)

Then `sudo apt-get -y install php5.6-mysql` [output](https://pasteboard.co/HeiaN5F.png)

Is there anyway I can install PHP 5.6?

Comment: [PHP 5.6 does not receive active support](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) and it only has another 9 months of security support. Bite the bullet today and upgrade your old project so it will work with PHP 7 instead of investing time trying to get dead dependancies  working.

Comment: 17.04 is EOL... you should 16.04 on it if you want LTS, then look into using LXD then you could have 12.04 right upto 18.04 containers.. amongst other distros on the same machine..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I do not have more knowledge about ubuntu/linux, so not able to get your point

Comment: You should ask this question on askubuntu.com. Anyway, Read  https://askubuntu.com/a/756186/586277 for deleting and installing PHP 5.6. and another thing. Install LTS version if you want to use your machine for developing. 17.04 is EOL (End of Life).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Having two different versions of PHP installed sounds like a recipe for trouble IMHO. You could compile from source, perhaps? https://blacksaildivision.com/php-install-from-source

Comment: @LawrenceCherone How can I get 16.04? Will my installed application work ok with 16.04 version?